# Ignore special characters when a user submits a Magento search?

Tags: magento, search, character

Is there a way that anyone is aware of to ignore special characters when a Magento (1.5.1.0) search is submitted?

For example: If someone submits #955 as a product search, it returns zero results, but if 955 is searched, the appropriate product results are returned.

Looking through the search terms in the Magento admin, many, many users are including the "#" in front of model numbers when they search, and I'd like to filter that if possible so it is ignored when the search is submitted.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a result controller in a custom module which will check for any special character and will filter that out.

See this class in Magento Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Act. Your custom module should extend this class, and you need to write a method for that.

Hope this will give you some idea.